pod install failed with Error installing JitsiWebRTC (react-native)
I'm trying to run an iOS build for a react-native project. This build runs fine on ANDROID.
However, running pod install displays this error:
TERMINAL ERROR MESSAGE
The project has react-native-webrtc version 111.0.6 installed.
"react-native": "^0.70.8"
I have searched for any related issues but i cant find any.
